# Electron + Ionic - ion-row height does not adjust to its content

Tags: html, css, angular, electron, ionic4

I have an Electron application built using Angular + Ionic 4. There is a simple screen which contains three `ion-row` elements within `ion-grid`.

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row class="top-part">
    <ion-col>
      <form>
        <!-- Just one input -->
      <form>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-select></ion-select>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  ...
</ion-grid>
```

Problem is that the height of the row does not adjust to the height of its content and causes layout to break. Blue field is shown by Chromium Dev Tools as an actual height, green lines show desired height and red lines show another `<ion-row>` which is now overlapped a bit.
[image: Broken layout]

Upon inspection I found out that both `ion-row` and `ion-col` have their height set incorrectly. I tried adding `height: fit-content` to CSS which **fixed issue with `ion-col` height** but adding it to `ion-row` has no effect. Since I'm trying to avoid setting height to exact value, I'm struggling to find the solution. Any idea what should I try?

*Important thing to mention is, that it only happens within Electron. Both Chrome and Firefox don't have this issue.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent one MD on this thing and I found out, that the middle row has `flex-grow: 1`. It means it'll take all available space it can. It looks like there is some issue with that in Chromium because it forces top `ion-row` and bottom `ion-row` to shrink to be shorter than actual height of its content.

**Solution is simple**, just add `flex-shrink: 0` to both top and bottom rows.